# Area 51 proposal: Science Educators

Tags: discussion

I recently proposed Science Educators, a site where teachers and tutors of any field of science (physics, chemistry, biology, earth sciences) can ask questions.

I decided to join forces with all sciences since Mathematics Educators is not getting sufficient traffic to graduate (currently at 1.5 questions out of 10 per day, which is low since the site is quite old), therefore I considered it unlikely that any of the sites (physics, chemistry, biology, earth sciences) could get launched an Educators site on there own.

So, if you are interested, please follow the proposal, and create and vote for example questions.

Since the old one was closed, here is a new proposal:

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Science Educators]

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/915/ -- note though, that there is a "Science Educators Q&A" listed in this link that isn't yours (which means someone else tried and failed, though I cannot tell you why).

Comment: Math Educators has been closed already? I remember it has reached the beta phase

Comment: @Ooker No, I'm sorry for giving you that impression. I meant to say it is too low to graduate. But every site that passed private beta will not be closed anymore unless there is no-one interested enough to keep the site clean of spam and such. So Math Educators will not close.